# How to display the following face in Android

Tags: android

I have the following character: ༼ つ ◕_◕ ༽つ

It goes in `strings.xml` like this:

```
<string name="faceIcon_5">༼ つ ◕_◕ ༽つ</string>
```

and Android Studio and seems to display the character fine.

However when it is actually run on the phone it looks like this:

[image]

It seems like some of the characters cannot be displayed by android. What can I do?

Comment: Works fine for me on 6.0.1, but shows exactly like yours on KitKat (4.4.4), what version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: On 4.4.4: http://imgur.com/mXhHwKi  On 6.0.1: http://imgur.com/7EUsye4

Comment: @DanielNugent Do you know if I can find the default font used by Android on 6.0.01

Comment: Probably, the system font used by Android **6.01** supports those glyphs, while the font in lower Android version doesn't. Try providing a font which has all the Unicode glyphs in your assets folder and then use it in your Views.

Answer (score 2):

You have to allow unicode for some of those characters.

```
// Your Text View.
tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
// Get A Unicode Font
Set a unicode font to your textview. Via TypeFace font = typeface.createfromasset(getassets(), someUNIcodeFont):
// set The font to your font
tv.setTypeface(font); 
//set face to textview.
tv.setText(R.String.faceIcon_5);
```